# RDLC - Report not showing Data only headings Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

Please help me i need your few time .this is below my code it is showing headings only not the rows data.But the data is coming from this database please take a look.THANKS

```
 FineDataSet.CountryDataTable fc = new FineDataSet.CountryDataTable();
 FineDataSetTableAdapters.CountryTableAdapter fsad = new FineDataSetTableAdapters.CountryTableAdapter();

 fsad.Fill(fc);
 //ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet12_SubCityGrandTotal", fsw.TableName);
 //rds.DataSourceId = fs;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Myreport2.rdlc");
 ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
 Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource();
 rds.Name = "DataSet1";

 rds.Value =  fc.TableName;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
 //ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
 ReportViewer1.DataBind();

 GridView1.DataSource = fc;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here -
This is how you have to set your data from DB to report -

```
   viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset_name_as_in_rdlc_file", dataset.Tables[0]));
```

Here the name "dataset_name_as_in_rdlc_file" should be same as in the rdlc file you use.and dataset.Tables[0] is the dataset you get from your query.